# Hiding Div When Clicking Inside Div

Tags: javascript, html, hide

I have this code that when you click on something, a hidden div appears, but the only way to get the div to disappear is to click outside of it. I was wondering if there was a way to make it so that you're able to click the div itself to make it disappear.

Java:

```
function toggle() {
var ele = document.getElementById("about");
//var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
if(ele.style.display == "block") {
    ele.style.display = "none";
    //text.innerHTML = "show";
}
else {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    //text.innerHTML = "hide";
}
}
```

CSS:

```
#about {height: 100%; width: 100%; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); position: fixed; bottom: 0px; left: 0px;}
```

HTML:

```
<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();"><img src="http://companionplants.com/images/small-plant2.jpg"></a>

<div id="about" style="display: none;">
Text here
</div>
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: @j08691 just did! sorry

Comment: How do you call your toggle function? Also the code for your function above is missing a closing `}`.

Comment: @j08691 just updated again, my apologies! i'm still quite new to this website as you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the same toggle call on the div overlay itself:

```
<div id="about" onclick="toggle()" style="display: none;">Text here</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tvbv757b/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add an `onclick` function.

HTML:

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    testing
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var mainDiv = document.getElementById('mainDiv');

mainDiv.style.cursor = 'pointer';
mainDiv.onclick = function() {
    mainDiv.style.display = "none";
}
```

[jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/rz9101st/)

If you want to alternative between two dividers, then see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/jkezrj1t/).

Comment: thanks so much! for some reason that didn't work with my code... would it be possible for you to look at the updated full code i posted? i think it's because my div is initially hidden.